# Traveral maze and Depth First Search

Tags: c++, c

I have learned DFS today and I tried practice tonight.

I encounter a problem  in my program.

http://codepad.org/quq5FcwR

```
void dfs(int x,int y){
  if( maze[x][y]==0 ) maze[x][y]=2;
  if( maze[8][8]==2 ){
    flag=true;
    return;
  }
  if( maze[x+1][y]==0 && x+1<9 ){
    maze[x][y]=2;
    maze[x+1][y]=2;
    dfs(x+1,y);
    if(f lag==false ){
      maze[x+1][y]=0;
      maze[x][y]=0;
    }
  }
  else if( maze[x][y+1]==0 && y+1<9 ){
    maze[x][y]=2;
    maze[x][y+1]=2;
    dfs(x,y+1);                                
    if( flag==false ){
      maze[x][y+1]=0;
      maze[x][y]=0;
    }
  }
  else if( maze[x-1][y]==0 && x-1>0 ){
    maze[x][y]=2;
    maze[x-1][y]=2;
    dfs(x-1,y);                                
    if( flag==false ){
      maze[x-1][y]=0;
      maze[x][y]=0;
    }
  }
  else if( maze[x][y-1]==0 && y-1>0 ){
    maze[x][y]=2;
    maze[x][y-1]=2;
    dfs(x,y-1);                                
    if( flag==false ){
      maze[x][y-1]=0;
      maze[x][y]=0;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

1.
The link is the program that I write, but I don't know how to find the shortest path.

2.
Can you give me some  advice about how to do it with stack, I use only recursive.I have seen the wiki about it, but cannot still understand how to use the stack.(eg how to use 1-D array to record the point about 2-D array, I am so confused about it)

Thanks for you spend time reading my problems。

Comment: Please post the relevent code into your question, and ensure that your indentation ins't half a page like it is in codepad

Comment: be nice. also, if you don't like deep indentation, i suggest you avoid kernel code.

Comment: @111111: Please, no rudeness to (at least seemingly) beginners. When I started programming I had no indentation at all, and I have gotten a long way from there. We have all been beginners once.

Comment: @LiKao I genuinely didn't mean to come across as rude, I just wanted to ensure that if he did copy it here it wouldn't be indented like that, because stackoverflows code listing puts scroll bars on and that is even ahrder to read.

Comment: Depth First Search (or search based on a stack) is the wrong tool for Shortest Path: you want Breadth First Search (or a search based on a queue) or Best First Search (or a search based on a priority queue) depending on whether you consider the number of hops or the distance.

Comment: At everybody who is downvoting this: Could you please help this guy at least to somehow improve this question? Downvoting without comment is like hitting someone on the head and not saying what he did wrong. Do not discourage beginners like this.

Comment: I apology for this situaion, I will notice that and I will edit later.

Comment: I still not familiar with how to ask and edit the problem,sorry!><

Comment: @111111: Ok, sorry for the flames then. Emotions get lost easily online, so the intention is not always clear.

Comment: @LiKao no problem tone is the first thing to go when writing.

Comment: @Liang-YuPan: I fixed your indentation, so you can see what it should look like. Here some advices for indentation: 1) Use little but discernible space for indentation. 2-3 spaces are the norm. Some people prefer single tabs over spaces but this only works in an editor, where you can set the tab-size. 2) Closing brackets should be on the same colum as the line where they were started. 3) Spaces at selected places make the code much more readable. Have a look at the way I re-edited your code and you'll probably agree that it is much more readable than before.

Comment: @LiKao Thx for your help, I have learned  a lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple points to comment on in this case:

1) The simplest stack is the recursion stack, which you already seem to be using looking at your code. I.e. whenever you call `dfs()` from the function `dfs()` itself, all variables will be put onto the stack. In your case, when you call x and y will be saved for returning later. I.e. once you come back from `dfs()` x and y will have the same value they had before you called.

2) Before returning you have to undo the last change. In the beginning of your function you set `maze[x][y]=2`. Before you return you'll have to undo this, because this space might lead into a dead end.

3) DFS can be used to find any path with low memory usage. However the path found by DFS may not be the shortest one. There is another algorithm called BFS which will find the shortest path, but has a much higher memory usage. Then there is iterative DFS, which will find the shortest path, has low memory consumption, but takes more time. You'll have to decide what you want and then pick your algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to do a BFS for finding shortest path, than DFS.

You can use 2 1-D arrays to denote a point in 2-D maze.

I used to have xq[maxlength], yq[maxlength] as queue for traversing a 2-D maze.

when you want to insert a new position (xi,yi) into the queue do

```
xq[back] = xi;
yq[back] = yi;
back++;
```

when you want to get a point (xp,yp) from a queue,

```
xp = xq[front];
yp = yq[front];
front++;
```

Initially have front and back to be 0. Queue is done, and you can do a BFS using it.